# Creating Rails 3.1 app with Postgresql database (OSX Lion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I cant seem to find an up-to-date guide to creating a new Rails 3.1 app with a Postgresql database. I would greatly appreciate a guide through that process.

Comment: do you want installation guideline as well?

Comment: no, just what has to happen after "rails new appname --database=postgresql"

Comment: See my answer - run `bundle` and you're finished.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since Rails 3, the framework is completely database-agnostic.

What that means is, all you have to do is 2 things:

1. Include the `pg` gem in your Gemfile: `gem 'pg'`
2. Make sure your `database.yml` file is using `postgresql` as the adapter.

You can accomplish this automatically when you create a new app by appending the `--database=postgresql` flag:

```
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

But if you've already created the app, then just comment out `gem 'sqlite3'` in your Gemfile, add in `gem 'pg'`, run `bundle`, and then change your `database.yml` file to use the correct adapter.

Of course, it goes without saying that you will also need to install PostgreSQL itself, but that is something you can easily find on google.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to: "change your database.yml file to use the correct adapter"

Comment: Try the `rails new` command posted in the answer and take a look at the generated `database.yml` file. (It shows: `adapter: postgresql`)

Comment: where is the database located within the app? for instance, if i want to access it via a GUI, where is the file i need to load?

Comment: Postgres is a complete database server, sort of like MySQL. There's not a single file you can load to see it and the data isn't stored in your application anywhere. Check [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) for Postgres GUI options.

Comment: If you want to locate the `database.yml` file it should be in `your_app/config/database.yml`

Comment: Alternate shortform for the same, `rails new myapp -d=postgresql`

Answer (score 23):

To elaborate on bricker's answer... After running:

```
$ rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

Here is what your database.yml will look like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:
```

Running:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create:all
```

will create the databases for you if you have PostgreSQL installed. The easiest way to install PostgreSQL is http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found you have to either add the username, in the example above - myapp, to the PostgreSQL database or change the username to an existing user.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4, bricker's answer does not work, at least not for me.

This command does the trick instead:

```
 rails new new_app --d = postgres
```